# Is there a common basic template or style for movie posters?

Tags: posters, history

I am designing an app about collecting movie posters (original ones combined with some funny/creative factors).

Since there are different kinds of movies (horror, romantic, action, etc.), **I need to find a unifying graphic style for them.**

My target user group is mostly male European/US movie goers aged 16-40.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

"Most attractive" is a pretty hard question to answer, but if you want to emulate a range of styles in a movie poster, you're in luck because movie posters tend to follow a range of clichés.

FontShop has a blog called the FontFeed, and they have a [large archive of posts](http://fontfeed.com/archives/category/fonts-in-use/screenfonts/) where they review movie posters. Read ten of 'em in succession and you'll start to see patterns, particularly in typography. There is a lot of discussion about fonts which is important to emulating whatever style you choose to emulate. (You'll see lots of Trajan in here!)

[This site](http://www.dailyinspiration.nl/has-hollywood-lost-its-creativity/) will be a bit quicker to scan and will give you some great overall trends in color and composition as well as how they tend to relate to movie themes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, these two sites are very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

iTunes has a similar feature that sums up genres nicely:

[image]